# Does Ruby have a built-in do ... while?

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements, keyword

Ruby has a wealth of conditional constructs, including `if`/`unless`, `while`/`until` etc.

The `while` block from C:

```
while (condition) {
    ...
}
```

can be directly translated to Ruby:

```
while condition 
    ...
end
```

However, I can't seem to find a *built-in* equivalent in Ruby for a C-like `do ... while` block in which the block contents are executed at least once:

```
do { 
    ... 
} while (condition);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136793/is-there-a-do-while-loop-in-ruby

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a "do ... while" loop in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136793/is-there-a-do-while-loop-in-ruby)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

...The best I could come up with is the `loop` construct with a `break` at the end:

```
loop do
    ...
    break unless condition
end
```

Comment: Yes, this is the approach that Matz recommended. see http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/6745

Answer (score 12):

You can do

```
i=1
begin
  ...
  i+=1 
end until 10==x
```

(you can also tack on a while clause to the end of begin..end)

see p 128 of Flanagan/Matz Ruby Prog'g Lang book: This is something that may be removed in releases after 1.8

Comment: That would be the direct translation of do...while from C. It's Matz's comment that makes me a bit nervous about using this

Comment: I think i should start testing in 1.9 in ubuntu and OS X, it's not hard

http://blog.michaelgreenly.com/2007/12/multiple-ruby-version-on-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 6):

```
number=3
begin
 puts  number
 number-=1
end while number>0
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use

```
while condition
  ...
end
```

Comment: while condition isnt the same as do while condition.
in the do while case the code gets executed at least once.

Comment: The point of the question was that it's obvious how to do a `while (condition){...}` but not so obvious how to do a `do{...} while(condition)`, which runs the inside block at least once no matter what.