# Check for unique value before saving record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My setup: Rails 3.0.9, Ruby 1.9.2

I want to generate a unique random number for a column right before creating a new record. What is the most efficient way to do this in Ruby? I understand that I can use validates_uniqueness_of but I want to ensure uniqueness beforehand.

Comment: Not sure why you wouldn't want the database to handle this.

Comment: it may help to know what you're using the number for

Comment: @Dex, reason is because the API is called from multiple devices and platforms and error handling is questionable, so I prefer not to have to return errors.

Comment: @klochner, it's for an invitation code between 6-10 digits long

Comment: A unique constraint is letting the database handle this ;)

Comment: Yes but then I'll have to return the error, hoping to avoid the error in the first place :)

Answer (score 4):

How about a before_create or before_save AR callback?

Something like:

```
class ModelNameHere < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :generate_unique_number

  private
    def generate_unique_number
      begin
        self.number = unique_number_generator()
      end while (not ModelNameHere.find_by_number(self.number).blank?)
    end
```

The begin..end while is basically a do-while loop taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136793/is-there-a-do-while-loop-in-ruby).
Haven't tested though but I think it should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to absolutely ensure uniqueness in Ruby before saving the record, then wrap it in a transaction and lock the tables. Be aware that this can cause a significant impact on your performance.

```
self.class.transaction do
  connection.execute('LOCK TABLES table_name WRITE')

  # do your random generation until uniqueness validation passes here

  connection.execute('UNLOCK TABLES')
end
```

Personally, I think I'd rather place a unique constraint on the column in the database and catch the resulting exception in case you encounter a real race condition.

Comment: Good suggestion on locking the table but like you said, it's heavy. Putting a unique constraint is a reasonable compromise, guess I'll throw in a unique index constraint.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like...
self is new object

```
Object.currentkeys.each do currentkey 
    if self.key == current.key
   #The key is allready in use

    else
     #You have unique key
    end
end
```