# Ruby: until a new object has some property

Tags: ruby

How can I refactor the following code to avoid repetition?

```
  r = @lots.fetch @lots.keys.sample      
  until (neighbours r)
    r = @lots.fetch @lots.keys.sample
  end
```

I basically have a new `r` object that is picked randomly and I need to pick `r` till the selected one doesn't respond to certain criteria (`neighbours r`). How can I refactor it to avoid the repetition of getting r and keep getting it till a condition is reached? Thanks

Comment: your question could be rephrasen as "how do you write a do-while loop in Ruby?". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136793/is-there-a-do-while-loop-in-ruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would shuffle `@lots` (turn it into a two element array if needed) and then use [take_while](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-take_while) like this:

```
>> h = {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3} #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
>> h.to_a.shuffle.take_while { |k, v| v < 3 } #=> []
>> h.to_a.shuffle.take_while { |k, v| v < 3 } #=> [[:b, 2]]
>> h.to_a.shuffle.take_while { |k, v| v < 3 } #=> [[:a, 1]]
>> h.to_a.shuffle.take_while { |k, v| v < 3 } #=> [[:b, 2], [:a, 1]]
```

If you need the result as a hash again, just call `Hash[]` on it:

```
 >> Hash[h.to_a.shuffle.take_while { |k, v| v < 3 }] #=> {:a=>1}
```

In your case the condition for take while would be something like `{ |k, v| !(neighbours v)}`. Also if you want the elements from the starting hash to be repeatable, you'll have to do use something else instead of `shuffle`.

Comment: This is especially good, if the condition (`neighbours`) is rather improbable (+1). Otherwise, shuffling the whole hash in memory just to get a few random values might be overkill.

Comment: It's just an example of collection methods available in Ruby, it's up to OP to write code that does exactly what he wants. If `take_while` isn't the right tool, do a `drop_while` with negative condition and use `first` on the leftover collection. Also OP said nothing about hash sizes or memory constraints and I always prefer easy code over premature optimizations.

Comment: Note that with this approach, the `v`/`r` fulfilling the condition is not available afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

```
begin
  r = @lots.fetch @lots.keys.sample
end until neighbours r
```

Note that such code can easily lead to long running (or even infinite) loops if the condition `neighbours` is unlikely. In such cases better make sure you check every element just once as it is done in [Michael Kohl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8324019/908515).