# Stop parsing when hitting an empty line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, split, cloudmailin

I have a Rails app parsing incoming e-mails on Heroku using the Cloud-mailin add-on. The app recieves a list of prices in an e-mail and inserts them into the database.

This works fine, but if the e-mail contains for instance a signature in the bottom the code fails because it's also trying to parse that text.

Therefor I would like to rewrite the below parsing code to stop when it hits an empty line in the e-mail. All the price data is always at the top of the e-mail.

```
email_text = params[:plain]
email_text_array = []

email_text.split("\n").each do |email_line|
    email_text_array << email_line.split(" ")
end
```

How do I change the above to stop when it hits an empty line in the `email_taxt` variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `break` :

```
email_text.split("\n").each do |email_line|
  break if email_line.blank?  # ends loop on first empty line
  email_text_array << email_line.split(" ")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this question help: [Is there a "do ... while" loop in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136793/is-there-a-do-while-loop-in-ruby)

Edit 1:

From the above article I think something like this would work:

```
email_text.split("\n").each do |email_line| 
  break if email_line.length < 1
  email_text_array << email_line.split(" ")     
end
```