# Is there a way to 'cd ..' up a nested "if" statement tree?

Tags: ruby

I'm curious if there's a way to have the program go back up the `if` statement stack?

Ideally, the program would return to line 2 and prompt the user for the input variable, then continue to evaluate like it did the first time.  Think of it like a cursor in a text editor, I just want to move it from either of those two comments back up to line 2.  The two places of interest are commented out below:

```
while true
input = gets.chomp
    if input != input.upcase
        puts "HUH?! SPEAK UP, SONNY!"
    elsif input == 'BYE'
        puts "HUH?! SPEAK UP, SONNY!"
        input = gets.chomp
        if input == 'BYE'
            puts "HUH?! SPEAK UP, SONNY!"
            input = gets.chomp
                if input == 'BYE'
                    puts "GOOD BYE!"; 
                    break   
                else
                    # return to top-level if statement
                end     
        else
            # return to top-level if statement
        end
    else
        random_year = rand(1930..1950)
        puts "NO, NOT SINCE #{random_year}!"
    end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "return to top-level if statement"? What should happen next?

Comment: In this code, if you will always return to top level if statement(and not to `input=gets.chomp`), it will loop forever, I have a strong feeling suggesting that.

Comment: This is really awful way of writing a sequential code

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `while` statement to set a condition flag and check it, which will loop back to the `while` statement if you don't change the flag:

```
flag = 0
while flag1 == 0
  if var = "string"
  then ...statements...
  flag1 = 1      ; this allows us to break out of this while loop
  else ...statements...
  end
end
```

If `flag1` is not 0 at the end of the `while` statement, the `while` statement will loop back. For two such conditions, you need to nest the `while` loops. You might have to re-order your statements to make multiple `while` loops work this way.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you show, you don't need to do anything to make the flow of execution go back to line 2. Just omit the `else` clauses in the two places you marked. The flow of execution will drop down to the bottom of the `while` loop, then loop back to the top, then go back to line 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this level of neasted ifs with:

```
byecount = 0
while byecount < 3
  input = gets.chomp

  if input == "BYE"
    byecount += 1
    next
  else
    byecount = 0
  end

  if input != input.upcase
    puts "HUH?! SPEAK UP, SONNY!"
  else
    puts "NO, NOT SINCE #{rand(1930..1950)}!"
  end
end
puts "GOOD BYE!"
```

Or you can write a catch..throw flow structure. (Really.. if you need to use it, something is wrong with your design)

```
catch :exitloop do
  while ...
    if ...
      if ...
        if ...
          throw :exitloop
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd write a similar exercise:

```
BYE = 'BYE'
HUH = "HUH?! SPEAK UP, SONNY!"

loop do
  input = gets.chomp

  if input != input.upcase
    puts HUH
    next
  end

  if input != BYE
    random_year = rand(1930..1950)
    puts "NO, NOT SINCE #{random_year}!"
    next
  end

  puts HUH
  input = gets.chomp

  if input == BYE

    puts HUH
    input = gets.chomp

    if input == BYE

      puts "GOOD BYE!"; 
      break   

    end     

  end

end
```

I used `loop` instead of `while`. Matz, the main man for Ruby, [recommends `loop`](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/6745). See "[Is there a “do … while” loop in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136793/is-there-a-do-while-loop-in-ruby)" for further discussion about it.

Comment: The links you posted says nothing against `while ... end`. He is against `begin ... end while ...`, because it does not do what is looks like at first look. (I prefer `loop do` too)