# Why does ruby eagerly evaluate expressions for 'while' but not 'if'

Tags: ruby

Notice how the `while` version evaluates the expression, but the `if` version does not.

```
begin
  puts 'hi'
  1
end while false
# => hi
# => nil 

begin 
  puts 'hi'
  1
end if false
# => nil
```

But if we use an expression without `begin` ... `end` it will not eagerly evaluate it.

```
puts 'hi' while false
# => nil
```

Is there a reason for this seeming discrepancy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `begin-end-while` (also called do-while in other languages) [is supposed to run the block of code *at least* once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/136815/493122) (therefore leading to the printing of "hi") and repeat it as long as the condition is met.

```
while X
    Y
end
```

is **not** equal to:

```
begin
    Y
end while X
```

The first will never execute the `Y` block of code if the condition `X` is never met. The second will, firstly, evaluate the block of code `Y` once and then will check if the condition `X` is met: if it is, then it runs the block `Y` again and again until the condition `X` evaluates to `false`.

A normal `begin-end-if` block, instead, is just considered like any other if block: it will be ignored (or just not executed) if the conditional expression evaluates to `false`.

```
if X
    Y 
end
```

is, instead, equal to:

```
begin
    Y
end if X
```

which is the same as:

```
Y if X
```

Comment: Your link has a link to Matz saying that he regrets this feature. http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/6745

Comment: @jshen, yup, you should use `loop do` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The postfix notation is just a shorthand for having the conditional beforehand.  This is "rewritten" by the interpreter for the condition to be beforehand.

However, a do-while loop is its own loop type.  It is not just a shorthand for having the while() up front.

Answer (score -2):

You are assuming that `begin` .. `end` is a compound statement, but it isn't, `begin` starts a region with exception handling and `end` just marks the other boundary of that region. The contents of the `begin`...`end` block are still multiple statements.

Ruby doesn't need compound statements because it has programmer-friendly block terminators. But you can make them with `(...)`, so try something like:

```
(
  puts 'hi'
  123
) if false
```

Comment: Begin ... End returns the value of the last expression.