# how to write a while loop in erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I have a table with two columns level, and slot. each level can have many slots, but I have made one table that models this case. example

```
level    |   slot
1        |   1
1        |   2
1        |   2
2        |   1
2        |   2
2        |   2
```

and in my erb template I want to make a table that will model this case by making something like a grid.
The issue so far, is I want somethink like two loops to handle this situation. for each level, I get the number of slots and display them. the provided `each` loop is not helping. I am thinking of creating a variable that will keep track of the level variable, and when it changes, I call the inner loop. but this does not loop efficient to me.

I am thinking also of creating a json object and make the slots apeats as an array inside the level variable, but I have no idea from where to start this.

or is there a way to write a while loop in the erb template?

Answer (score 5):

You can write a loop in ruby (erb) this way:

```
<% loop do %>
  ...
  <% break if <condition> %>
<% end %>
```

See [Is there a "do ... while" loop in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136793/is-there-a-do-while-loop-in-ruby)

Comment: Just a note that loops in ruby are to be avoided because they leak their variables outside of their scope, unlike using enumerators.

Answer (score 4):

ERB is just ruby

```
<% @collection.each do |value| %>
  <%= value %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: yes I know, that, but  i want something like another loop while inside that. with that, I can do something like while(level = 1){//do something here}

Answer (score 2):

It can still be one table. I would create a variable called `@slots` in your action, and call `.each` on it in your erb view like so:

```
<% @slots.each do |slot| %>
 <% if ...  %>
  <div class="left-column">
    <%= slot.level %>
  </div>
  <div class="right-column">
    <%= slot.id %> <!-- or whatever var you you want --> 
  </div>
 <% else %>

 ...

 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This way each new `slot` will be automatically added to the collection, and you don't need to worry about changes to the `level`