# Scraping, following pagination links

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, mechanize

I am trying to scrape a website which has multiple page results like "1, 2, 3, 4, 5...".
Every pagination number is a link to another page and I need to scrape every page.
So far I came up with this:

```
while lien = page.link_with(:text=> link_number.to_s)
            link_number = link_number + 1
            body = page.body
            html_body = Nokogiri::HTML(body)
            html_body.css('#personne tbody tr').each do |person|
              puts person.css('td').first.text.to_s
            end
            page = lien.click
          end
```

But this never scraps the last page.

Please help me write better code that scrapes the last page.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please supply a _minimal_ example of the HTML that demonstrates what you're trying to handle. Also, when working with Mechanize it's *NEVER* necessary to use `Nokogiri::HTML(body)` to get a DOM of the HTML. Mechanize already uses Nokogiri and you can easily access its internal DOM.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that on the last page there will not be a link to a next page. Thus the condition on the while statement evaluates to `nil` and so the main body of the while is not executed.

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10713963/3464137) you'll need something like this:

```
loop do
  lien = page.link_with(:text=> link_number.to_s)
  link_number = link_number + 1
  page.parser.css('#personne tbody tr').each do |person|
    puts person.css('td').first.text.to_s
  end
  break unless lien
  page = lien.click
end
```