# Batching when using ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, batching, syck, psychparser

I am busy writing an migration that will allow us to move our yamler from Syck to Psych and finally upgrade our project to ruby 2. This migration is going to be seriously resource intensive though so I am going to need to use chunking.

I wrote the following method to confirm that the result of the migration I plan to use produces the expected result and can be done without down time. To avoid Active record performing the serialization automatically I needed to use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`

My method that describes the transformation is as follows

```
 def show_summary(table, column_name)
  a = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute <<-SQL
   SELECT id, #{column_name} FROM #{table}
  SQL
  all_rows = a.to_a; ""
  problem_rows = all_rows.select do |row|
    original_string = Syck.dump(Syck.load(row[1]))
    orginal_object = Syck.load(original_string)

    new_string = Psych.dump(orginal_object)
    new_object = Syck.load(new_string)

    Syck.dump(new_object) != original_string rescue true
  end

problem_rows.map do |row|
  old_string = Syck.dump(Syck.load(row[1]))
  new_string = Psych.dump(Syck.load(old_string)) rescue "Parse failure"
  roundtrip_string = begin
    Syck.dump(Syck.load(new_string))
  rescue => e
    e.message
  end

  new_row = {}
  new_row[:id] = row[0]
  new_row[:original_encoding] = old_string
  new_row[:new_encoding] = roundtrip_string
  new_row
  end
end
```

How can you use batching when making use of  `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` ?

For completeness my update function is as follows

```
  # Migrate the given serialized YAML column from Syck to Psych
  # (if any).
  def migrate_to_psych(table, column)
    table_name = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote_table_name(table)

    column_name = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote_column_name(column)

    fetch_data(table_name, column_name).each do |row|
      transformed = ::Psych.dump(convert(Syck.load(row[column])))

      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute <<-SQL
         UPDATE #{table_name}
         SET #{column_name} = #{ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote(transformed)}
         WHERE id = #{row['id']};
      SQL
    end
  end

  def fetch_data(table_name, column_name)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all <<-SQL
       SELECT id, #{column_name}
       FROM #{table_name}
       WHERE #{column_name} LIKE '---%'
    SQL
  end
```

Which I got from http://fossies.org/linux/openproject/db/migrate/migration_utils/legacy_yamler.rb

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can easily build something with SQL's `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses:

```
def fetch_data(table_name, column_name)
  batch_size, offset = 1000, 0
  begin
    batch = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all <<-SQL
      SELECT id, #{column_name}
      FROM #{table_name}
      WHERE #{column_name} LIKE '---%'
      LIMIT #{batch_size} 
      OFFSET #{offset}
    SQL
    batch.each do |row|
      yield row
    end
    offset += batch_size
  end until batch.empty?
end
```

which you can use almost exactly the same as before, just without the `.each`:

```
fetch_data(table_name, column_name) do |row| ... end
```

HTH!

Comment: By the way, I always try to avoid using ActiveRecord models in migrations. Simply because the model's source code is subject to change but my migration might still be used a year from now to set up test databases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! This is really helpful ! Ye I had some pain earlier this year on my project with models changing and then data migrations that used active record failing.

Comment: This works nice, just one note [not use begin; end until syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136793/is-there-a-do-while-loop-in-ruby)